# WCF Services via IIS error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: vb.net, wcf, iis-7

I'm running a WCF service through IIS with `.svc` files. If I visit the page in a web browser, I get the "You have created a service." page, which is good. But when I go to use an application that uses these web services, I get the following error:

> *The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.*

I've already googled around, and I've run the following commands on the computer that IIS is hosted on:

- `"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe" –i`
- `"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -i`

This is with IIS7 and WCF 3.0. The service application (and all related libraries) are all compiled with .NET 3.5, and the IIS7 app pool is configured to use .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there was a misconfiguration in the web.config file of the site hosting the service. Nevermind!

Comment: What was the misconfiguration?

Comment: That was almost six months ago, I have no idea... sorry.